# How to prevent columns showing different width when scrolled down (juggling columns) in table in an angular app?

Tags: angular

Following is a mock of an app I'm building.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3mrzkr

It requires a thirdparty scrolling module.
This is because my real app handles a lot of data. So virtual scroller is required.
I've tried cdk-virtual-scroller and decided to move with ngx-virtual-scroller cause cdk-virtual-scroll doesnot support sticky header.

Following is the main code:

```
// component.html file

<virtual-scroller #scroll [items]="data">
<table>
<thead #header>
<tr>
<th *ngFor="let column of columns"> {{column}}
</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody #container>
<tr *ngFor="let item of scroll.viewPortItems">
<td *ngFor="let column of columns">
<name-comp [name]="item.name" *ngIf="column === 'name'">
</name-comp>

<p>
{{column === 'id' ? item.id :
column === 'postId' ? item.postId :
column === 'email' ? item.email :
column === 'body' ? item.body 
: ''}}
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</virtual-scroller>
```

```
component.ts file

export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

  data = DATA

  columns = ['postId', 'id', 'name', 'email', 'body']
}
```

Here in ngx-virtual-scroller sticky header is working fine.
But the columns keeps on juggling around while scrolling up/down.

How can I prevent this?

I;ve tried a lot of ways like piping the width for each columns, custom width directives, adjusting min-width and max-width.... a lot.. Someone please help!

[please don't get concerned about anything else. Only requirement/problem I've right now is to fix this juggling of columns when scrolled down]

Comment: calculate widths for columns and enforce them not to change

Comment: I tried that way with a custom directive, to observe the width for each cells and maintain a min width with a maximum limit. That turns out not working properly.

Comment: if you allow them to have some place to resize they will resize you need to setup exact width and maybe setup overflow to hidden on cells cause they may cause some width change even if they are set to some exact size

Comment: Yep. I've adjusted the text-overflow to ellipsis so that I can maintain a max width for each cells.

Comment: But this turns out that it is not working properly. I hope there would be a better way. Can you please show some code.

Comment: you can try using grid layout instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:
Put this style on Table element

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(2em, 1fr));
```

Put this style on on thead tr

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(7em, 1fr));
```

Put this style on tbody tr

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(10em,1fr));
```

Soution 2
   Use [mat-table](https://dev.to/jwp/angular-material-table-in-20-minutes-15f4) and get rid of virtual scroller, mat table has a built-in paginator.

Comment: I like your solution. It is working best in large breakpoints. Can you please suggest some method to prevent anysort of wrapping when the breakpoint is small/medium? Instead in here when the overflow is greater than allowed we can have a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: This is the modified layout:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3mrzkr

Comment: Wrapping too is a css function, read up on text wrapping : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/